# Get contacts from SIM card with SDK constants of methods

Tags: java, android, sdk, contacts, sim-card

I've seen various answers saying how to get the SIM contacts, but none of them seems to use an SDK constant. Only `content://icc/adn`, `com.android.contacts`, or `com.android.contacts.sim`. None include a constant like android.contacts.SIM_URI (doesn't exist, just an example).

So I'd like to know if there is any constant to be the URI OR if there is some alternative to using URIs, like methods. I've found SubscriptionManager, but the terms used are technical and I don't understand them enough, unless I'd spend a lot of time trying the methods. If no one knows I will though, but if anyone does know, it would spare me a lot of time.

About the constants, I'd rather not be forced to put those 3 and some if statements to see if they fail, then try another --> what if all 3 fail because the constant is no longer used? Shouldn't there be an actual constant defined somewhere? (I can't find it)

Thanks in advance for any help!

**PS:** Would be cool if I could differenciate the various SIM cards the phone could have so I could have the contacts from the one I want. But if I can't, will be already an advancement and I'd appreciate it too.

**Update:** Just found out ICC means Integrated Circuit Card, which they use to name a SIM card. ADN seems to be Abbreviated Dialing Numbers, which means numbers like 911, it seems. Though, this doesn't seem to help much finding a constant or anything else.